# How to connect FFTW libraries to a software?

Tags: linux, dll, centos, maya, fftw

I have connected FFTW library (http://www.fftw.org/)to a custom mentalray DLL that I have created in C++(A DLL file I have compiled on Linux (CENTOS) Using netbeans. I put this DLL in the software (Autodesk Maya) in a folder for adding custom plugins. The problem is I have installed FFTW on the computer and I dont know how to link Maya to the FFTW library. On windows I would put the FFTW dll in the folder that contains the maya.exe file that is the application Launch exe file.
Basically my question to a normal LINUX programer is if I install the FFTW libraries on linux and create a .dll for a software that links to it how do I get the software to link to the FFTW libraries?
let me know if you need me to provide anymore info..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special - so long as the FFTW libraries are at the expected location (`/usr/local/lib`) then you can just link to then as normal (`gcc ... -lfftw3 ...`).

Comment: I have linked them to the .so file I have created but when I run the application that calls my .so file it cant find the FFTW files .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to compile the right version: fftw floats (i.e., fftwf) versus fftw doubles. You should have a `libfftw3f.3.so` file, for example.

If you are using `dlopen` to call functions in fftw, place the `.so` file you generated somewhere in your `$PATH`.

If the mental ray "DLL" is a static library, you should configure fftw with `--enable-static --disable-shared` and run `sudo make install`.

If the mental ray "DLL" is a dynamic library, you should configure fftw with `--disable-static --enable-shared` and run `sudo make install`.

To be safe, you can do both.

`sudo make install` will place the fftw "DLLs" in the right place, as long as your mental ray "DLL" is using fftw conventionally (i.e., importing a `fftw.h` file).

Check for linker errors when you try to build your "DLL." If you see linker errors, you neglected to run `sudo make install` and your DLL won't work at all regardless of what you do with fftw.